# CoreData getting attribute type - how to determine if it is a primitive

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsentitydescription, nsattributedescription

I'm trying to get all the attributes for an entity and then determine their type - I know I can do something on this line:

```
if(![[thisAttribute attributeValueClassName] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
```

but how do I check for a BOOL, Float or Integer?

Here's my code so far:

```
//get the attributes for this entity - we need to parse the dictionary of data we want to store and convert its contents from NSStrings to whatever type the entity requires
    NSEntityDescription* entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:strEntityName inManagedObjectContext:myMOC];
    NSDictionary* dictAttributes = [entity attributesByName];

    for(NSString* strThisKey in dictAttributes) {

        NSAttributeDescription* thisAttribute = [dictAttributes objectForKey:strThisKey];
        NSString* strAttributeType = [thisAttribute attributeValueClassName];

        //look for a match in the data keys (the dict we passed) with the entity keys
        for(NSString* strDataKey in dictDataToStore) {

            //found
            if ([strDataKey isEqualToString:strThisKey]) {

                if(![strAttributeType isEqualToString:@"NSString"]) {

                    //check for whatever else (@"NSDate", @"NSNumber", etc.)
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

OK, I misunderstood what was being returned to me from NSAttributeDescription, I edited the code and essentially answered my question. Hope this helps someone else out.

Comment: Well, it is my understanding that CoreData is not letting you save any primitive, so BOOL, float and int, all of them are wrapped by a NSNumber. It is not clear to me how you can check the primitive type from the entity.

Comment: isn't it just a matter of checking the `attributeType` property of the `NSAttributeDescription` object (return an `NSAttributeType` value) [see here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSAttributeDescription_Class/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSAttributeType)?

Comment: Hi Leonardo - yeah, I saw that and that's why I changed my question. So I guess that's my question - when you set up an attribute you can choose BOOLEAN, INTEGER 16, 32, etc, how can you tell what type the attribute is if it coverts all to NSNumber?

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks, that was it. Barking up the wrong tree. : D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `NSEntityDescription` and `NSPropertyDescription` APIs to determine the kind of a modelled entity.

I would enumerate through `NSAttributeDescription`'s `NSAttributeType` constants

```
switch (thisAttribute.attributeType) {
  case NSInteger16AttributeType: { /* do something */; } break;
  case NSDecimalAttributeType  : { /* do something */; } break;
  case NSStringAttributeType   : { /* do something */; } break;
  case NSBooleanAttributeType  : { /* do something */; } break;
  // etc
  default: break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I eventually did but you get the win for posting in the form of an answer! : D

Comment: I wrote this while you were discussing in the comments. You have to tick the check mark, though.