# identify coreData Attribute's type

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift2

Im writing a library that allows developers to apply SQL code on coreData like so:

```
let manager = coreSQL()
manager.prepare("INSERT INTO Entity (name, age) VALUES (?,?)")
manager.execute(["Chuck Norris" , "76"])
```

to insert in coreData i use this

```
let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
let newRow = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(tableName, inManagedObjectContext: context)
if (columnsArray.count == values.count){
    for i in 0 ..< columnsArray.count{
        newRow.setValue(values[i], forKey: columnsArray[i])
    }
    do {try context.save()} catch _ {}
}
```

- **columnsArray = ["name", "age"]**
- **values = ["Chuck Norris" , "76"]**

the problem is that in my coreData object the age Attribute is of type Integer and as you may noticed Chuck Norris's age is String so when i try to execute my application i get an error :

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unacceptable type of value for attribute: property = "age"; desired type = NSNumber; given type = _TtCs19_NSContiguousString; value = 76.'**

The question is: how can i identify the attribute type in order to cast the value to the same type

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CoreData getting attribute type - how to determine if it is a primitive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19815306/coredata-getting-attribute-type-how-to-determine-if-it-is-a-primitive)

Comment: thanks that partially solved my problem but i just noticed that by setting the values array to [AnyObject] instead of [String] solved my problem without adding more code

Comment: If you are doing to leave the catch blank like that, just do a `try!` instead.  Otherwise you are hiding errors and your library is going to be a nightmare to debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can identify the attribute type by asking the entity:

```
let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
let newRow = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(tableName, inManagedObjectContext: context)
let attributes = newRow.entity().attributesByName()
if (columnsArray.count == values.count){
    for i in 0 ..< columnsArray.count{
        let attributeDescription = newRow.entity.attributesByName[columnsArray[1]]
        switch attributeDescription.attributeType {
        case StringAttributeType:
        }
        newRow.setValue(values[i], forKey: columnsArray[i])
    }
    try! context.save()
}
```

Comment: we ve already found 2 solutions! but since ive tested your code and it worked ive checked your question