# Getting NSNumber exception while converting data based on attribute type

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift3, xcode8

Using the pattern shown here: [identify coreData Attribute's type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36533895/1107226)

```
// setting up entity and attributes list
let entity: NSManagedObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: entityName, into: backgroundContext)

let entityAttributes = entity.entity.attributesByName

...

// looping through provided property names and values
let propertyType: NSAttributeType = entityAttributes[propertyName]!.attributeType

switch propertyType {

// StringAttributeType, used in link example, isn't available in Swift 3, Xcode 8.0
//case StringAttributeType:

// using instead: NSAttributeType constants                 
case .stringAttributeType:
    let propertyValue: String = propertyValues[idx]
    entity.setValue(propertyValue, forKey: propertyName)

case .integer16AttributeType:
    let propertyValue = Int16(propertyValues[idx])
    entity.setValue(propertyValue, forKey: propertyName)

...
```

However, getting exception with Int16 value:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unacceptable type of value for attribute: property = "this_prop_name"; desired type = NSNumber; given type = _SwiftValue; value = 3.'

I thought we no longer had to do NSNumber conversions in CoreData with Swift. Or, am I having a low-brain-oxygen moment?

What is the correct Swift 3 way to convert an Int16 (or any other number value) via an entity's attribute type?

Comment: I recommend to use `NSManagedObject` subclasses. Swift 3 makes the handling much easier.

Comment: I am not sure if I see what you are actually trying to achieve, but Swift does not map Int16 to NSNumber (that will change with Swift 3.1). Setting an integer attribute via `setValue:forKey:`  requires an `Int` or `NSNumber` argument.

Comment: @MartinR, I'm reading the data from a file. The entity's properties have mixed types (most are strings, some are ints, some are doubles), but the file read results in all String values. So, I need to convert those String values to the appropriate type required for their associated entity properties. vadian: I am using NSManagedObject subclasses.

Comment: Try `let propertyValue = Int(propertyValues[idx])` for the integer attributes.

Comment: That worked, @MartinR! Enter that as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the Core Data attributes via Key-Value coding requires values
which are instances of `NSObject` subclasses, such as `NSString` or
`NSNumber`.

Up to Swift 3.0, only certain scalar types can be bridged to `NSNumber`
and back, such as `Int`, `UInt`, `Double`, `Float` but not the fixed-size
types like `Int16`. (This will change in a future Swift release, compare
[SE-0139 Bridge Numeric Types to NSNumber and Cocoa Structs to NSValue](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0139-bridge-nsnumber-and-nsvalue.md).)

Therefore in

```
entity.setValue(propertyValue, forKey: propertyName)
```

`propertyValue` needs to be an `Int` or `NSNumber`. In your case
of an "Integer 16" attribute, `Int` would be large enough to hold
all possible values:

```
let propertyValue = Int(propertyValues[idx])
```